# C# System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized' on a tableAdaptormanager,updateall call

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I apologize in advanced as I see many similar questions however none that fit my distinct case.

I am making a database for my employers using SQL (converted from access) and visual studio 2017 c#. The newest issue I have come across is receiving an

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized'

error when trying to delete an object from a datatable and then try to save it. I can add and alter pieces then save it with no error. I have not changed any of the code regarding saving back to the SQL server that visual studio auto-generated for me.

Snooping around The piece of code that it uses to save is

```
this.Validate();
this.clientsBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.clientEmployerDataSet);
```

I can not find where it keeps the delete command however so I can't see if something is misaligned there.

Comment: You need the StackTrace from the Exception which will help you find the offending line and everything that happened prior to it. Somewhere the code is not setting the sql text on the DbCommand/SqlCommand instance.

Comment: clientEmployerDataSet is a DataSet and the Insert, Update and Delete statements can be defined in DataSet, either using the visual studio's design time wizard, or defined and assigned dynamically at run time.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue on line 5764 of the dataset designer, the line just says

```
this._adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = "";
```

instead of having the proper SQL delete command put in.

Edit: Not as solved as I  would like as it turns out. I have no clue what the 'while' condition should be (after finding out that DELETE FROM does work...too well and deletes everything (that's why we have backups)).